# how to add product to cart customer without create order by magento API?

Tags: api, magento, cart

how to add product to shopping cart customer Magento without create order by API?

I use this snippet Code: https://gist.github.com/roberto-butti/3509401

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get rid of this part, as you can see in the comment it creates an order:

```
// create order
echo "\nI will create the order: ";
$resultOrderCreation = $proxy->call($sessionId,"cart.order",array($shoppingCartId, null, $licenseForOrderCreation));
echo "\nOrder created with code:".$resultOrderCreation."\n";
```

So to add products to cart from beginning, use lines 1-83 from provided snippet.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I used this way and not working :(